# dictionary x[0:1] only gives me x[0]

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

when doing a decryptor, I can't solve this one problem. i sign two numbers to a letter using a dictionary. The problem is that it only signs one number

```
szyfr={x[0:1]:'a', x[2:3]:'b',x[4:5]:'c', x[6:7]:'d'}
```

x stores 54 numbers saved in a file and that's the key. The problem is, that when i print this dict, It says this:

```
{'1': 'a', '3': 'b', '9': 'c', '6': 'd', '': ' '}
```

the first one currently should have been "14" and the second should have been "37"

Has anyone been in a similar problem before? (Sorry if I'm doing something wrong but it's my first post here and English is my second language)

Comment: Why should the first one be 14 and the second be 37? Is x[1] == 4 and x[3] == 7? The slice operator uses start:end, where end is not included - and it returns a list, not the two numbers concatenated. Since you haven't included what `x` is, it's hard to say anything useful

Comment: When you take a slice, the second index is `one more` than the last position you want.  So  to get 'Pi' from "Pieselm" you need to specify `"Pieselm"[0:2]`

Comment: Oh sorry, x is a number that is stored in a file and the first 8 numbers are "14379868"

Answer (score 2):

Python list slicing does not include the element of the last index of the slice.

You need to change it to `szyfr={x[0:2]:'a'...}`
to get `{'14': 'a',}`  and so on..